# How to drop more than one constraint at once (Oracle, SQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I'm changing constraints in my database and I need to drop some of them. I know that for a single constraint, the command is following:

```
ALTER TABLE tblApplication DROP CONSTRAINT constraint1_name;
```

However, when I try

```
ALTER TABLE tblApplication DROP (
  CONSTRAINT constraint1_name,
  CONSTRAINT constraint2_name,
  CONSTRAINT constraint3_name
);
```

it doesn't work and I need to do:

```
ALTER TABLE tblApplication DROP CONSTRAINT constraint1_name;
ALTER TABLE tblApplication DROP CONSTRAINT constraint2_name;
ALTER TABLE tblApplication DROP CONSTRAINT constraint3_name;
```

Is there a way to remove more than one constraint in a single command? I'd like to avoid repeating `ALTER TABLE tblApplication`, just like with the `ADD` command:

```
ALTER TABLE tblApplication ADD (
  CONSTRAINT contraint1_name FOREIGN KEY ... ENABLE,
  CONSTRAINT contraint2_name FOREIGN KEY ... ENABLE,
  CONSTRAINT contraint3_name FOREIGN KEY ... ENABLE
);
```

Comment: In your add example you have used curly braces instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to repeat 'drop constraint' per constraint. e.g.

```
alter table t1
drop constraint fk1
drop constraint fk2
/
```

Edit: I tested this against Oracle 11, and it worked fine. Don't know about older versions.

Comment: To be fair, the Oracle documentation on ALTER TABLE is a fairly difficult read. It took me a while to find the one sentence that states that multiple drop clauses are permitted. The syntax diagram does not make it obvious at all, and one could make the case that it does not permit it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative form to drop constraints related to a column in a table, also dropping the column with CASCADE:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP (columnName) CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

It is tested on Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

example: we can drop constraints in MySQL by creating constraints to the variables like this way.

```
create table sample(id int, name varchar(30), marks int, constraint uid unique(id), constraint un unique(name));
alter table sample drop constraint uid, drop constraint un;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can drop multiple at once:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE NAME
DROP CONSTRAINTS CONSTRAINT VALUE
DROP CONSTRAINTS CONSTRAINT VALUE;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read [answer] and don't SHOUT.